# in UITableView, can I have two sections with the cells of each section to be variable length?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, cell

and also, by doing that, does it align to the iPhone UI guidelines?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. And there is a nice article here:

[iPhone SDK: Resizing a UITableViewCell to Hold Variable Amounts of Text](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-resizing-a-uitableviewcell-to-hold-variable-amounts-of-text/)

My best guess is that it is in line with UI guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can even use different subclasses of UITableViewCell in the same tableView.